# In Octave, how can I call ls with options?

Tags: octave, ls

I'm trying to get a list of filenames to iterate through in my Octave program. I currently call

```
x = ls
```

and that works fine.
However, I want a list of only text files. I can call

```
ls *.txt
```

But I can't call

```
x = ls *.txt
```

Is there any way to do that? The workaround I've found is

```
x = eval("ls *.txt")
```

but I'm hoping to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29339425/1609556) which explains why you are calling `ls` wrong, you are also wrong in calling `ls` to begin with.  This function returns a char array with the list of files which is mostly useless for anything other than display at the Octave prompt.

Instead, consider use `glob`:

```
files = glob ("*.txt")
```

which will return a cell array of filenames.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Calling-Functions.html#Calling-Functions

```
x = ls ("*.txt")
```

If you call a function without (), all arguments are interpreted as strings but this only works if you don't want to store the result. So

```
foo bar baz
```

is equivalent to

```
foo ("bar", "baz")
```